# Excel charts and graphs automatically updated with new raw data

Tags: excel

Looking for advice and suggestions on how to build this out...

I am exporting raw data from a data source and pasting it into Excel. The data source cannot directly connect with Excel (hence pasting it in). The data is used to populate a bunch of charts and graphs, similar to a dashboard. The raw data will change depending on the data request. Instead of rebuilding all the charts and graphs, I'd like to paste the new data into the Excel workbook and refresh all the charts and graphs. What is the recommended approach?

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: [Use named ranges for your data](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html). That way you can switch data in and out, and the chart should update.

Comment: probably nitpicking, but @BruceWayne's link uses **dynamic** named ranges, which is a more sophisticated employ of basic named ranges. :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Ah, thanks for pointing that out, I forgot they're different.  I do think though this would be one of your quicker options Mike, so it may be worth trying on a small sample table, and if it works, just scale up from there.

Comment: @BruceWayne and Mike. Yes, it's definitely the way to go. I was not suggesting otherwise, in case that was not clear.